# MVC3 set value to textbox type datetime in opera

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, input, textbox

I have datetime input in my ASP.NET MVC3 app:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Article.PublishedDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Article.PublishedDate)
</div>
```

In Opera it makes special input for date and time but when I edit my model it´s empty and I want to set it to value. In other browsers it´s regular textbox and there is datetime set. Code which is generated thanks that code is:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Publish date is required" id="Article_PublishedDate" name="Article.PublishedDate" type="datetime" value="30.3.2012 10:00:00" data-default-value=""/>
```

How can I fix it and set datetime in Opera too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to format your datetime according to the [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) standard

HTML5 input datetime spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime.html

So your value needs to be formated something like this:

```
<input ... type="datetime" value="2012-03-30T10:00:00" ... />
```

To format a date as RFC3339 you can call:

```
DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
```

You can accomplish this by adding a DisplayFormatAttribute to you Article.PublishedDate:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ}")]
public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
```

Problem now (at least for me) is that the property now always stays formated like this. You could use an EditorFor Template for this:

```
@model DateTime?

@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    attributes.Add("type", "datetime");

    attributes.Add("class", "text-box single-line");

    //since this is a constraint, IsRequired and other constraints 
    //won't necessarily apply in the browser, but in case script 
    //turns off readonly we want the constraints passed
    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly)
    {
        attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }

    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
    {
        attributes.Add("required", "required");
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ") : String.Empty, attributes)
```

Based on [DateTime.cshtml](https://github.com/paultyng/Html5EditorTemplates/blob/master/src/html5Templates.Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml)

And for local dates:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
  var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  attributes.Add("type", "datetime-local");
  attributes.Add("class", "text-box single-line");

  if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
  {
    attributes.Add("required", "required");
  }
}
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") : String.Empty, attributes)
```

Based on [DateTime-Local.cshtml](https://github.com/paultyng/Html5EditorTemplates/blob/master/src/html5Templates.Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime-Local.cshtml)

Comment: It´s exactly what I was looking for but I have problem that when I add or edit article It gets time from input + 2 hours and when I am editing article in input there is 04:02 and there should be 16:02. I think that these problems are because some kind of converting between 24hours/12hours time but don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: You could try to use <input type="datetime-local" /> this one uses the following format: DateTime.ToString("yyy-MMM-ddThh:mm:ss")

Comment: Added some EditorFor Templates i use these instead of the DisplayFormatAttribute.
You should put these in the "Views/Shared/EditorTemplates" folder

Comment: I edit my templates in that folder, remove DisplayFormatAttribute but still same problem. Should I change @Html.EditorFor(...)?

Answer (score 0):

The way the HTML is rendered by MVC is not really subject to change between browsers.

`type="datetime"` is a new input type in HTML5 ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp))

I suspect you are using an older version of Opera, which does not yet support this input type.